# Download all ubuntu packages

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

I will be using Ubuntu on a computer without internet connection. Is it possible to download from some place all (or most of the) Ubuntu packages for my distrubution (and it's version)? I'd like to download it as an ISO image or zip archive (not individually every package) and burn on DVD.

thank you for advice

Comment: @Jorge Castro : The question is different but the answer can be concluded from the source [How can I install software offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)